How do I kill or close a port
Because I am getting the following error message on my server when I try to run my webhook_server.js application:
   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
0|webhook_ |   errno: -98,
0|webhook_ |   syscall: 'listen',
0|webhook_ |   address: '::',
0|webhook_ |   port: 3003

I run the following command
sudo lsof -i:3003
...indeed it logs out:
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    2369 ubuntu   18u  IPv6  15268      0t0  TCP *:3003 (LISTEN)

How do I kill or close port 3003?

Does this answer your question? How to kill a process running on particular port in Linux?

You should probably find out the purpose of the application that is listening on port 3003 rather than just arbitrarily killing it. Then decide how best to deal with the port conflict.
